# Java: How does the Array provide instant-lookup

Tags: java, arrays, lookup

More specifically, how does the Array object in Java allow users to access each bucket in constant time?  I understand that Java allocates memory equivalent to the specified size at initialization, but what about the structure of it allows such rapid lookup?  The reason I am asking is because it's something not available in any other data structure save those that use Array representations of data.

Another (possibly silly) question is why can't other data structures provide such quick lookup of the stored data?  I guess this question can/will be answered by the answer to the first question (how Arrays are implemented).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array is just stored as a big contiguous block of memory.

Accessing an element is a matter of:

- Finding where the data starts
- Validating the index
- Multipying the index by the element size, and adding the result to the start location
- Accessing that memory location

Note that this is all done in the JVM, not in byte code. If arrays didn't exist at a JVM level, you couldn't fake them up within pure Java. Aside from anything else, arrays are the only objects in Java which logically vary in size between instances within the same JVM. (It's possible that some JVMs have clever systems to use compressed references in some cases and not in others, but that's an implementation detail rather than a logical difference.)

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand this correctly, an Array essentially holds pointers to every object it holds.  So another way of creating an "Array" would be to store references to every single object that would otherwise be stored in an actual Array?

Comment: @user3483560: Well an `int[]` doesn't store pointers - it stores just the data, sequentially. But if you have something like `String[]` or `Object[]`, then yes, that just holds references... just as any other variable would hold a reference rather than the actual object data. I'm not sure what you mean by your "another way of creating an array"... you'd have to know at compile-time what the size of the array would be, whereas you don't need to know that with real arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I suppose a better way of wording the second part of my comment would be: an Array is simply a collection of pointers (given that it is storing objects), and putting this collection of pointers into an Array is simply a matter of housekeeping and ease of access (rather than, say, creating references to each individual object and accessing them that way).

Comment: @user3483560: I'm still not sure what you're saying. An array with an element type that's a reference type is just a collection of references... it's *not* storing objects, it's storing references, just as if you created a linked list data structure. There's no special pointer type which is used instead of a reference.

Comment: Jon, my apologies, I think I am either confused or not expressing myself clearly or both, but at any rate, thank you very much for your help.